# UIDatePicker with countDownTimer shows “0 hours 2 min”

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker, countdowntimer

How can I change "hours" to "hour" and "min" to "mins" in UIDatePicker with countDownTimer.

Comment: You can't change `UIDatePicker`'s text

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify texts in UIDatePicker, you can just set some colours to it. I think you can go for UIPickerView if you have to have hour instead of hours and so on.